# Return a query from a function?

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4 and I want to create a function that returns a query with many rows.
The following function does **not** work:

```
create function get_names(varchar) returns setof record AS $$
declare
    tname alias for $1;
    res setof record;
begin
    select * into res from mytable where name = tname;
    return res;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The type `record` only allows single row.

How to return an entire query? I want to use functions as query templates.

Comment: As always, the version number of PostgreSQL would help. :)

Comment: Please note that -though esthetically  pleasing- set-of-rows functions tend to perform badly in real life. The point is that they will not be 'broken up' by the query optimiser. A simple query like "select from f() where not exists (select ... from f())" can lead two two, maybe even three sort steps. Use with care.

Comment: @wildplasser: While that *can* happen if you actually nest table functions, they *do* perform perfectly fast as long as you don't. Faster than the query itself, actually, because the query plan can be cached.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: Yes and no. Performed as a singleton, they may spare you the compilation and planning costs; used in combination with other "real" query elements, they can be disastrous, causing too many avoidable scans and sort steps.

Comment: @wildplasser: "in combination with other query elements" = to nest. Is there any other way? I don't see a downside if I use a couple of table functions sequentially inside a transaction, or am I missing something here?

Comment: That would be a "function as in procedure". A void function, in C terms. Or maybe a scalar. But in the OP's sense: if you want a function to return a set of rows, you may actually want to do things with the result, such as combining it with other results.

Comment: @wildplasser: I am explicitly talking about table functions. We have a number of web applications that get their data this way. And it works as fast as it gets. No downside, as long as you don't nest (like join a couple of them together). For that I would write a new table function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_names(_tname varchar)
  RETURNS TABLE (col_a integer, col_b text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT t.col_a, t.col_b  -- must match RETURNS TABLE
   FROM   mytable t
   WHERE  t.name = _tname;    
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call like this:

```
SELECT * FROM get_names('name')
```

**Major points:**

- Use [`RETURNS TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html), so you don't have to provide a list of column names with every call.
- Use [`RETURN QUERY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING), much simpler.
- Table-qualify column names to avoid naming conflicts with identically named `OUT` parameters (including columns declared with `RETURNS TABLE`).
- Use a named variable instead of `ALIAS`. Simpler, doing the same, and it's the preferred way.
- A simple function like this could also be written in `LANGUAGE sql`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_names(_tname varchar)
  RETURNS TABLE (col_a integer, col_b text) AS
$func$
SELECT t.col_a, t.col_b  --, more columns - must match RETURNS above
FROM   mytable t
WHERE  t.name = $1;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```