# PostgreSQL: update a schema when views from another schema depend on it

Tags: postgresql, view, schema

Here is my setup. I have two schemas: `my_app` and `static_data`. The latter is imported from a static dump. For the needs of my application logic, I made views that use the tables of `static_data`, and I stored them in the `my_app` schema.

It all works great. But I need to update the `static_data` schema with a new dump, and have my views use the new data. The problem is, whatever I do, my views will always reference the old schema!

I tried importing the new dump in a new schema, `static_data_new`, then trying to delete `static_data` and rename `static_data_new` to `static_data`. It doesn't work because my views depend on tables in `static_data`, therefore PostgreSQL won't let me delete it.

Then I tried setting `search_path` to `static_data_new`. But when I do that, the views still reference the old tables!

Is it possible to have views that reference tables using the `search_path`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views are bound to the underlying *objects*. Renaming the object does not affect this link.
I see basically **3 different ways** to deal with your problem:

1. **`DELETE` your views** and re-`CREATE` them after you have your new table(s) in place. Simple and fast, as soon as you have your complete create script together. Don't forget to reset privileges, too. The recreate script may be tedious to compile, though.
2. Use **table-functions** (functions `RETURNING SETOF rows` or `RETURNING TABLE`) instead of a views. Thereby you get "late binding": the object names will be looked up in the system catalogs at execution time, not at creation time. It will be your responsibility that those objects can, in fact, be found.

   The `search_path` can be [pre-set per function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) or the `search_path` of the executing role will be effective for objects that are not explicitly schema-qualified. Detailed instructions and links in [this related answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7548734/939860).

   Functions are basically like prepared statements and behave subtly different from views. Details in [this related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684).
3. Take the **`TRUNCATE` and `INSERT`** route for the new data instead of `DELETE` and `CREATE`. Then all references stay intact. Find a more detailed answer about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8826879/939860).

   If foreign keys reference your table you have to use `DELETE FROM TABLE` instead - or drop and recreate the foreign key constraints. it will be your responsibility that the referential integrity can be restored, or the recreation of the foreign key will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess the simplest is to go with 1. and store the `my_app` tables in another schema.

Comment: @Artefact2: I find [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) very useful for that kind of operation. It presents the complete drop and create scripts for a any selected object.

Comment: Yes, I use it as well, though `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` are just more convenient for scripts & such.