# PostgreSQL Function Returning Table or SETOF

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

Quick background: very new to PostgreSQL, came from SQL Server. I am working on converting stored procedures from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. I have read Postgres 9.3 documentation and looked through numerous examples and questions but still cannot find a solution.

I have this select statement that I execute weekly to return new values

```
select distinct id, null as charges
     , generaldescription as chargedescription, amount as paidamount
from mytable
where id not in (select id from myothertable)
```

What can I do to turn this into a function where I can just right click and execute on a weekly basis. Eventually I will automate this using a program another developer built. So it will execute with no user involvement and send results in a spreadsheet to the user. Not sure if that last part matters to how the function is written.

This is one of my many failed attempts:

```
CREATE FUNCTION newids
RETURNS TABLE (id VARCHAR, charges NUMERIC
             , chargedescription VARCHAR, paidamount NUMERIC) AS Results
Begin
SELECT DISTINCT id, NULL AS charges
     , generaldescription AS chargedescription, amount AS paidamount
FROM mytable
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM myothertable)
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Also I am using Navicat and the error is:

> function result type must be specified

Comment: You need to use `LANGUAGE sql`

Comment: Still receiving the same error when creating function with the Navicat tool. If I execute the command in a query editor window it gives me a syntax error at or near RETURNS

Answer (score 5):

You *can* use PL/pgSQL here and it may even be the better choice.

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

But you need to fix a syntax error, [match your dollar-quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql/12172353#12172353), add an explicit cast (`NULL::numeric`) and use [`RETURN QUERY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548292/return-a-query-from-a-function/7548734#7548734):

```
CREATE FUNCTION newids_plpgsql()
  RETURNS TABLE (
     id         varchar
   , charges    numeric
   , chargedescription varchar
   , paidamount numeric
   ) AS  -- Results  -- remove this
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
SELECT ...;

END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

***Or*** use a simple SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION newids_sql()
  RETURNS TABLE (
     id         varchar
   , charges    numeric
   , chargedescription varchar
   , paidamount numeric
   ) AS
$func$
SELECT ...;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Either way, the `SELECT` statement can be more efficient:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id, NULL::numeric AS charges
     , t.generaldescription AS chargedescription, t.amount AS paidamount
FROM   mytable t
LEFT   JOIN myothertable m ON m.id = t.id
WHERE  m.id IS NULL;
```

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Of course, all data types must match. I can't tell, table definition is missing.
And are you sure you need `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Thank you. Lots of useful information.

Sometimes we have duplicate rows in that table so I keep Distinct to weed them out.