# SQL view with count depending on current user

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-view

Aim:

1. List all unique events
2. Have a dedicated column called `reviewed` based on the current user
3. Events must be listed event if current user is not invited

Possible cases:

1. User is invited
2. User is not invited

An event is reviewed by each "confirmed" user (not all of the invitations are confirmed)
Conditions to be "reviewed":

- review exists
- there is at least one attachments linked to this review

I have 4 tables in Postgresql 14.7.

- events
- invitations (1-1/user/event)
- review (0-1/invitation)
- attachments (0-n/review)

Here they are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.events (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    start_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    end_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE public.invitations (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    status integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL,
    event_id bigint NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE public.reviews (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    reviewable_id bigint NOT NULL,
    reviewable_type character varying NOT NULL,
    comment text
);

CREATE TABLE public.attachments (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    attachable_id bigint NOT NULL,
    attachable_type character varying NOT NULL
);
```

I got an SQL view for that but it is wrong because `reviewed` did not match the current user invitation (it is random, based on invitation creation).
Here is current code I have

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
  SELECT
    ((e.enable_review = true AND r.id IS NOT NULL AND count(a) > 0 ) OR e.enable_review = false)    AS reviewed,
  e.*
  FROM events e
  LEFT JOIN invitations i ON i.event_id = e.id
  LEFT JOIN reviews r ON (r.reviewable_type = 'Invitation' AND r.reviewable_id = i.id)
  LEFT JOIN attachments a ON (a.attachable_type = 'Review' AND a.attachable_id = r.id)
  GROUP BY e.id, r.id;)
```

I've read [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) dozens of times but I'm not sure it fits on my case

In my mind, this view was "temporary" until I scope the results with the current user invitations.

I have part of the solution using `row_number`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
  SELECT
    ((e.enable_review = true AND r.id IS NOT NULL AND count(a) > 0 ) OR e.enable_review = false)    AS reviewed,
  e.*,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY i.event_id ORDER BY i.id DESC) AS rn,
  i.id as manual_invitation_id
  FROM events e
  LEFT JOIN invitations i ON i.event_id = e.id
  LEFT JOIN reviews r ON (r.reviewable_type = 'Invitation' AND r.reviewable_id = i.id)
  LEFT JOIN attachments a ON (a.attachable_type = 'Review' AND a.attachable_id = r.id)
  GROUP BY e.id, i.id, r.id;)
```

Then I `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `manual_invitation_id` when I want to scope with the current user, combining it with `WHERE rn=1`.
But `rn` can be any number, not only one. So scope is not working.

I don't even know if it's possible in a single query. I want to avoid sub queries since it's one of the most used in the app. Additionally, it's inside a Rails app so I'm not sure subqueries can be handled that easily with ActiveRecord.

Comment: I think the first query gets quite close to the expected output. Perhaps you should add an invitation.user_id to the select and group statements - and then you can query the view for the "current user". Another approach within your Rails-App could be the through-statement: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association - so you can get the invitation and the attachement and check, if one exisits.

Comment: Reviews seen to be connected to invitations instead of events. Why is that? One would expect a "review" concerns the event, not the invitation. More generally, it's so much easier to give an answer based on the full picture. Table definitions, Postgres version. Ideally a fiddle with some test data.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter actually each user (fully invited) need to add a review to the event. So an event has many reviews as it has invitations fully confirmed.

Comment: Please clarify the aim of the query. Do you want to list all even/invitation/review combinations in existence. The LEFT JOINs indicate as much. Be precise about the objective - in the question, not just as comment

Comment: I want the list of events with column `reviewed` as a boolean.

Comment: You mean you want the list of events, where the current user has an invitation? Please state your objective, right at the top, in clear, plain English. Not the implementation you are attempting, but the objective. And how does the current user come into this *exactly*? I don't see a `user_id` anywhere.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've rephrase the issue + added details on the schema + Postgresql version. I hope it's clearer.

Comment: Seems like I predicted `invitations.user_id` alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all events, with a flag `reviewed` for the current user:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (
         SELECT
         FROM   invitations i
         JOIN   reviews     r ON r.reviewable_id = i.id
         JOIN   attachments a ON a.attachable_id = r.id
         WHERE  i.user_id = $current_user_id             -- ???
         AND    i.event_id = e.id
         AND    r.reviewable_type = 'Invitation'
         AND    a.attachable_type = 'Review'
         ) AS reviewed
     , e.*
FROM   events e;
```

An [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) subquery expression is probably fastest.

Don't use a generic `VIEW` for this if you want the result for the current user. Use the given query, or wrap it into a set-returning [`FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html). Example:

- [PostgreSQL Function Returning Table or SETOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126789/postgresql-function-returning-table-or-setof/30127396#30127396)

Comment: I would like to avoid subqueries. Plus, here I'll scope all events where current user is invited but I want all of them. I've added plenty of details on the description. It was not clear enough. 

Comment: No reason to avoid `EXISTS`. The "subquery" is just another expression returning `boolean`.

Comment: I'm afraid of performance issues with a subqueries (I'm surely wrong).
Is it possible to have this in a view and still have `$current_user_id` as dynamic?

Comment: I am giving this query **because** I expect it to be fastest. A `VIEW` is the wrong tool to begin with, if you want the result to be customized for the current user.

Comment: Well, you *can* make a VIEW work if you insist. You need a way to build the current user ID into it (like with a function returning it). Filtering a generic view for the current user would be very inefficient.

Comment: Ok I get it. Thanks! 
Can I use a group on the EXISTS event if I already have one on the view I'm using for all other cases?

Comment: What's a "group on the EXISTS"?

Comment: I need to group review to be able to count the number on each. It's on my first view. 

Comment: Can't say. Maybe ask another *question* with the necessary details to make it clear. So that we don't have to ask for details many times.

Comment: Actually it is on the description of "reviewed". 
"there is at least one attachments linked to this review"

Comment: *"there is at least one attachments linked to this review" ... is already implemented in my query. No need to count, if all you need to assert is the existence of at least one.

Comment:  My bad. You don't need to count since it's a `INNER JOIN` and not a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like I was doing it previously. Sorry about that. I'll test it asap. Thanks again!

Comment: Wonderful @Erwin Brandstetter, I move this new column directly as a WHERE clause. it works like a charm. I've just added a clause on the `enable_review` from the event but all the rest is coming from you. Thanks again! ❤️

Comment: Last question, do you have a recommendation for self learning database performance improvements? My "I'm afraid of performance issues with a subqueries" is clearly an ignorance from my side.

Comment: The excellent manual. And answers from trustworthy users here on SO and on [dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Performance optimization is tricky, requires knowledge, experience and a scientific mind. Bon voyage! :)