# Unable to execute the function in plpgsql/postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql, set-returning-functions, sql-returning

I want to calculate distance from address points to all streets within a distance of 50 meters using plpgsql. I have tried the following function:

```
Create or Replace Function get_dist(ad geometry, st geometry)
Returns double precision AS
$$
Begin
Insert into street(Distance)
Select ST_Distance(ad.geom, st.geom) from ad
Left Join st ON ST_DWithin(ad.geom, st.geom, 50.0);
Return ST_Distance(ad.geom, st.geom);
End
$$
Language plpgsql volatile;
```

Creating the function gives no error but when I try to call it using this command:

```
Select get_dist(ad.geom, st.geom) from ad
Left Join st ON st.gid = ad.gid;
```

I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ad"
> LINE 1: SELECT ST_Distance(ad.geom, st.geom)
> ```

Can someone please highlight what is wrong with the function (creating the function and calling it)?

Comment: Pass whole records - ad / st, or geometry... In the function - if ad/st is geometry - then rewrite inner select...

Comment: How can you execute this function without getting errors? Are there tables `ad` and `st` in your database (since you are selecting from them)? Please describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For processing a single row or processing rows one-by one, you can use the SQL `RETURNING` clause of `INSERT` combined with the plpgsql `INTO` clause. Example:

- [Get default serial value after INSERT inside PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837643/get-default-serial-value-after-insert-inside-pl-pgsql/33837685#33837685)

But you are obviously trying to process a whole set at once.

> calculate distance from address points to ***all streets*** within a distance of 50 meters ...

Use a set-based approach. *Much* faster and cleaner. If you want to return rows from the `INSERT` *additionally* use a **set-returning function**. Example:

- [Return a query from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548292/return-a-query-from-a-function/7548734#7548734)

You would not need a function at all. Just this query:

```
INSERT INTO street(ad_geom, st_geom, distance, traffic_ct)  -- any columns in street
SELECT ad.geom, st.geom, ST_Distance(ad.geom, st.geom), ad.traffic_ct
FROM   ad
LEFT   JOIN st ON ST_DWithin(ad.geom, st.geom, 50.0)
RETURNING *  -- all columns in street
```

I guess you don't actually need anything returned any more, since this query does all you wanted, but I kept `RETURNING` as proof of concept. You can just skip it.

Use `[INNER] JOIN`instead of `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` if you don't want to include adresses with no matching street.

[The manual about `RETURNING` in  `INSERT`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#AEN84764)

> The optional `RETURNING` clause causes `INSERT` to compute and return
>   value(s) based on each row actually inserted [...] any expression
>   using the table's columns is allowed. The syntax of the `RETURNING`
>   list is identical to that of the output list of `SELECT`. Only rows
>   that were successfully inserted or updated will be returned.

If you *need* to wrap this into a plpgsql function (could also be a simple SQL function) -  and still return all rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_neighbours()
  RETURNS SETOF street AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   INSERT INTO street(ad_geom, st_geom, distance, traffic_ct)  -- any columns in street
   SELECT ad.geom, st.geom, ST_Distance(ad.geom, st.geom), ad.traffic_ct
   FROM   ad
   LEFT   JOIN st ON ST_DWithin(ad.geom, st.geom, 50.0)
   RETURNING *;  -- all columns in street
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM insert_neighbours();  -- use SELECT * FROM ... !
```

For simplicity I return the whole row, but you can return select columns as well. [See above example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548292/return-a-query-from-a-function/7548734#7548734)

---

> Creating the function gives no error

That's because PL/pgSQL currently only runs superficial syntax checks on `CREATE FUNCTION`. You have to actually execute the function to test it - and make sure that all branches of code in plpgsql functions get tested.

Answer (score 1):

What you *appear* to want is to calculate a distance between two geometries and then insert that distance in a table if it is than 50.0. The function would be like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_dist(ad geometry, st geometry) RETURNS double precision AS $$
DECLARE
    dist double precision;
BEGIN
    dist := ST_Distance(ad, st);
    IF dist < 50.0 THEN
        INSERT INTO street(Distance) VALUES (dist);
    END IF;
    RETURN dist;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, I doubt that you *really* want that. For starters, the inserted row in table `street` will be assigned `distance = dist` when the function is called and the condition met, but no other properties (except any default values). What you *really* want is not clear from your question, but I hope you can work from the code above to make a working function.

Comment: Thank you. It indeed, solved my problem and exactly what I wanted. If I also want to return the geom of selected streets which are in 50 meters then can it be done by modifying above function or do I have to do write a separate function?

Comment: The problem here is that you are not selecting anything from the `street` table. Or is `st` the same as `street`? What other data do you want to store in table `street`?

Comment: I wanted to store other data such as geometry of selected streets (geom), distance between address to selected streets (helped by you above) and traffic counts w.r.t. address table. Do I have to write separate function for each of them? Yes, ST is street table while ad is address table.