# PL/pgSQL function does not return all the results using record

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql, resultset, set-returning-functions

I am trying to create a complicated PL/pgSQL function that gathers some results from a query and then checks each one and returns it or not.

This is my code **so far**. The **`record` and `loop` part** confuse me.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION __a_search_creator(creator text, ordertype integer, orderdate integer, areaid bigint) RETURNS record
AS $$
DECLARE    
fromText text;
whereText text;
usingText text; 
firstrecord record;
areageom geometry;

BEGIN
    IF areaid IS NOT NULL
    THEN        
        EXECUTE format('SELECT area.geom FROM area WHERE area.id=$1')
        INTO areageom
        USING areaid;  
 
        FOR firstrecord IN 
        EXECUTE format( 
        'SELECT place.id, person.name, place.geom 
        FROM '||fromText||'     
        WHERE '||whereText)  
        USING  creator, ordertype , orderdate         
        LOOP    
        --return only data that the place.geom is inside areageom using PostGIS 
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
    RETURN firstrecord;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**I plan** to do some extra checks in the `loop`, as you can see and `RETURN` only data that the `place.geom` (lon/lat) is inside `areageom`. But since I am new to pl/pgsql, I am creating now **the first step**, just gathering all the data, put them in a `record` and return.

My problem is that, no matter what I try I keep getting only one result back. I call `select  __a_search_creator('johnson',8, 19911109, 20);` and I get `1,"seth johnson", 65485,84545` but I know I should be getting another row of results. Is there overwrite happening?

I tried putting `RETURN  NEXT firstrecord;` I tried something like

```
        select place.id from place INTO placeid;        
        select person.name from person INTO personname;
        select place.geom from place INTO placegeom;        
        firstrecord.id := placeid;
        firstrecord.name := personname;
        firstrecord.geom := placegeom;
```

That still brings back just one result, I tried testing just this `RAISE NOTICE '%', firstrecord.id;` that still brings back just one full set of result.

I don't know how to proceed, please advice.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the dynamic SQL in the first query is useless. You can replace that with  a plain `SELECT area.geom INTO areageom FROM area WHERE area.id = areaid;`

Answer (score 0):

You declared your function with `RETURNS record`, so it returns a *single* record (of unknown type).

Use `RETURNS SETOF record` to return a set of rows. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#id-1.9.3.67.6)

> The `SETOF` modifier indicates that the function will return a set of items, rather than a single item.

Better yet, use **`RETURNS TABLE`** with a proper table definition. Like you already had it in previous questions:

- [Syntax error in dynamic SQL in pl/pgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372364/syntax-error-in-dynamic-sql-in-pl-pgsql-function/48374384)
- [Using text in pl/pgsql brings empty set of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387285/using-text-in-pl-pgsql-brings-empty-set-of-results/48389150)

Related (with detailed explanation and links to the manual):

- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)
- [Return setof record (virtual table) from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955167/return-setof-record-virtual-table-from-function/17247118#17247118)
- [Return a query from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548292/return-a-query-from-a-function/7548734#7548734)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution on the problem

```
IF areaid IS NOT NULL
THEN                        
    EXECUTE format('SELECT area.geom FROM area WHERE area.id=$1')
    INTO areageom
    USING areaid;                      

    FOR firstrecord IN 
    EXECUTE format( 
    'SELECT place.id, person.name, place.geom FROM '||fromText||' WHERE '||whereText)          
    USING  creator, ordertype, orderdate

    LOOP
        IF ST_Within(firstrecord.geom , areageom)
        THEN
            RETURN QUERY VALUES(firstrecord.id, firstrecord.name, firstrecord.geom);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;        
END IF;
RETURN;
```

Thanks to @Erwin Brandstetter for the useful links.