# "INSERT INTO ... FETCH ALL FROM ..." can't be compiled

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6, database-cursor, set-returning-functions

I have some function on PostgreSQL 9.6 returning a cursor (`refcursor`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_returning_cursor()
  RETURNS refcursor
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  _ref refcursor = 'test_returning_cursor_ref1';
BEGIN
  OPEN _ref FOR
  SELECT 'a' :: text AS col1
  UNION
  SELECT 'b'
  UNION
  SELECT 'c';

  RETURN _ref;
END
$$;
```

I need to write another function in which a temp table is created and all data from this `refcursor` are inserted to it. But `INSERT INTO ... FETCH ALL FROM ...` seems to be impossible. Such function can't be compiled:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_insert_from_cursor()
  RETURNS table(col1 text)
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE _temptable (
    col1 text
  ) ON COMMIT DROP;

  INSERT INTO _temptable (col1)
  FETCH ALL FROM "test_returning_cursor_ref1";

  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT col1
  FROM _temptable;
END
$$;
```

I know that I can use:

```
FOR _rec IN
  FETCH ALL FROM "test_returning_cursor_ref1"
LOOP
  INSERT INTO ...
END LOOP;
```

But is there better way?

Comment: It would be a lot easier if the first function was defined as `returns table (...)` as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think that is the best solution.

Comment: The first function must return refcursor by task specification.

Comment: Aside: Use `UNION ALL` or a `VALUES` expression instead of `UNION` in the 1st query. But the whole approach is flawed. What kind of task specification would demand an inadequate technique?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter we are rewriting database from MS SQL to Postgre. MS SQL has procedures, so 1 procedure can return multiple tables. Postgre can't, so we decided to return setof refcursor, 1 refcursor for 1 table. That's why first function _must_ return refcursor (or setof refcursor), not table(). But I do not know an adequate way to insert data from refcursor to temp table.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. The new [SQL procedures in Postgres 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-createprocedure.html) are designed to also return multiple results eventually, but that's not implemented in pg 11, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `INSERT` and `SELECT` don't have access to cursors as a whole.

To avoid expensive single-row `INSERT`, you could have intermediary functions with `RETURNS TABLE` and return the cursor as table with `RETURN QUERY`. See:

- [Return a query from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548292/return-a-query-from-a-function/7548734#7548734)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_cursor1_to_tbl()
  RETURNS TABLE (col1 text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   -- MOVE BACKWARD ALL FROM test_returning_cursor_ref1;  -- optional, see below

   RETURN QUERY
   FETCH ALL FROM test_returning_cursor_ref1;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;  -- not IMMUTABLE
```

Then create the temporary table(s) *directly* like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 ON COMMIT DROP
AS SELECT * FROM f_cursor1_to_tbl();
```

See:

- [Creating temporary tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691243/creating-temporary-tables-in-sql/15700736#15700736)

Still not very elegant, but *much* faster than single-row `INSERT`.

Note: Since the source is a `cursor` only the first call succeeds. Executing the function a second time would return an empty set. You would need a cursor with the [`SCROLL` option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-DECLARATIONS) and move to the start for repeated calls.

Comment: But how can I write such intermediary function? It must read from cursor and return table, so it will have SELECT...FROM FETCH ALL... , but such construction is not allowed. I know only 1 workaround, but that way is awful.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote intermediary function with "RETURN QUERY FETCH ALL FROM ..." to convert cursor's data to the table and it worked.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНоздрев: Yes. And simplify your temp table creation. I added some more above.

Answer (score 0):

This function does `INSERT INTO` from `refcursor`. It is **universal** for all the tables. The only requirement is that all columns of table corresponds to columns of refcursor by types and order (not necessary by names).

`to_json()` does the trick to convert any primitive data types to string with double-quotes `""`, which are later replaced with `''`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_into_from_refcursor(_table_name text, _ref refcursor)
  RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  _sql       text;
  _sql_val   text = '';
  _row       record;
  _hasvalues boolean = FALSE;
BEGIN

  LOOP   --for each row
    FETCH _ref INTO _row;
    EXIT WHEN NOT found;   --there are no rows more

    _hasvalues = TRUE;

    SELECT _sql_val || '
           (' ||
           STRING_AGG(val.value :: text, ',') ||
           '),'
        INTO _sql_val
    FROM JSON_EACH(TO_JSON(_row)) val;
  END LOOP;

  _sql_val = REPLACE(_sql_val, '"', '''');
  _sql_val = TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM _sql_val);

  _sql = '
          INSERT INTO ' || _table_name || '
          VALUES ' || _sql_val;
  --RAISE NOTICE 'insert_into_from_refcursor(): SQL is: %', _sql;
  IF _hasvalues THEN    --to avoid error when trying to insert 0 values
    EXECUTE (_sql);
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```

---

Usage:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table1 (...);
PERFORM my_func_opening_refcursor();
PERFORM public.insert_into_from_refcursor('public.table1', 'name_of_refcursor_portal'::refcursor);
```

where `my_func_opening_refcursor()` contains

```
DECLARE
  _ref refcursor = 'name_of_refcursor_portal';

OPEN _ref FOR
SELECT ...;
```